# Why React.useEffect() doesn't execute after mounting the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-tsx

I'm trying to fetch timetables. I passed zero array as second parameter to useEffect(), so it should execute after the render, but somehow it doesn't execute even once. Can somebody explain what is going on in my code? Thanks in advance!

Here is where I call useEffect (log "Fetch was performed!" is not printed)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ITimetable } from "../models";

export function useTimetables() {
    const [timetables, setTimetables] = useState<ITimetable[]>([])

    async function fetchTimetables() {      
        try {
            const response = await axios.get<ITimetable[]>("localhost:8080/api/v1/timetable/all")
            setTimetables(response.data)
        }
        catch (err: unknown) {
            const error = err as AxiosError
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }

    useEffect( () => { 
        fetchTimetables()
        console.log("Fetch was performed!")
    }, [])

    return { timetables }
}
```

Here is the component where useActivities() called

```
import { Timetable } from "../components/Timetable";
import { useTimetables } from "../hooks/timetables";

export function MainPage() {
    const { timetables } = useTimetables()
    
    return (
    <>
        <NavigationPanel></NavigationPanel>
        <div className="timetables-view">
            {/* { timetables.map( timetable => <Timetable timetable={ timetable }></Timetable> ) } */}
            <Timetable timetable={ timetables[0] }/>
        </div>
    </>
    );
}
```

Timetable component

```
import { ITimetable } from "../models";
import { useActivities } from "../hooks/activities";
import { Activity } from "./Activity";
import "../css-components/Timetable.css";

interface TimetalbeProps {
    timetable: ITimetable
}

export function Timetable({ timetable }: TimetalbeProps) {
    const { activities, loading, error } = useActivities(timetable.id)

    return (
        <div className="activity-container">
            { loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
            { error && <div>{ error }</div>}
            { activities.map(
                activity => <Activity activity={ activity }/> 
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: That would only happen if the component did not render, which might mean it threw an error during rendering. `<Timetable timetable={ timetables[0] }/>` is passing `undefined` into `<Timetable>`. Does it handle `undefined` correctly?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can't figure out where I should add check of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect hook with an empty dependency array ([]) is executed only once after the initial rendering of the component. It is used to perform any side effects that don't need to be re-executed when some state or props change.

In your code, the useTimetables custom hook is called from the MainPage component, which triggers the execution of the useEffect hook defined in the useTimetables hook. The fetchTimetables function is called, and then the setTimetables function is called to update the timetables state variable with the fetched data.

Since the useEffect hook has an empty dependency array, it will not be executed again even if the timetables state variable changes later. This means that the fetchTimetables function will not be called again, and the console log message "Fetch was performed!" will not be printed again.

If you want to re-fetch the timetables data whenever some dependency changes (like a prop or state variable), you need to include that dependency in the dependency array of the useEffect hook. For example, if you want to re-fetch the timetables data whenever the loading state variable changes, you can write the useEffect hook like this:

```
        useEffect(() => {
      if (loading) {
        fetchTimetables();
        console.log("Fetch was performed!");
      }
    },

 [loading]);
```

This will ensure that the fetchTimetables function is executed again whenever the loading state variable changes

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is that useEffect is not executed once